# Deep Learning Model not working on Raspberry Pi 4 (ALSA ISSUES for USB Microphone)

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio, alsa, raspberry-pi4

I am working on a Trigger Word Detection System. I need to run the model on Raspberry Pi. The Code is working absoulutely fine on Windows PC. But on rasberry I am getting alot of warning with respect to ALSA. I have even changed my model to TFLITE instead of H5. But still no success.

Here is my code :

```
import sys
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from queue import Queue
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

import tensorflow as tf
# Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()


def detect_triggerword_spectrum(x):
   
    x = x.swapaxes(0, 1)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    input_data = np.array(x, dtype=np.float32)
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

    interpreter.invoke()

    # The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
    # Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
    #ou = 
    predictions = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

    #predictions = model.predict(x)
    return predictions.reshape(-1)

Tx = 5511  # The number of time steps input to the model from the spectrogram
n_freq = 101  # Number of frequencies input to the model at each time step of the spectrogram
chunk_duration = 0.5  # Each read length in seconds from mic.
fs = 44100  # sampling rate for mic
feed_duration = 10
silence_threshold = 100




def get_spectrogram(data):
    """
    Function to compute a spectrogram.
    Argument:
    predictions -- one channel / dual channel audio data as numpy array
    Returns:
    pxx -- spectrogram, 2-D array, columns are the periodograms of successive segments.
    """
    nfft = 200  # Length of each window segment
    fs = 8000  # Sampling frequencies
    noverlap = 120  # Overlap between windows
    nchannels = data.ndim
    if nchannels == 1:
        pxx, _, _ = mlab.specgram(data, nfft, fs, noverlap=noverlap)
    elif nchannels == 2:
        pxx, _, _ = mlab.specgram(data[:, 0], nfft, fs, noverlap=noverlap)
    return pxx




def has_new_triggerword(predictions, chunk_duration, feed_duration, threshold=0.477):
    predictions = predictions > threshold
    chunk_predictions_samples = int(len(predictions) * chunk_duration / feed_duration)
    chunk_predictions = predictions[-chunk_predictions_samples:]
    level = chunk_predictions[0]
    for pred in chunk_predictions:
        if pred > level:
            print("Detected")
            return True
        else:
            level = pred
    return False


def get_audio_input_stream(callback, chunk_duration=0.5, fs=44100):
    chunk_samples = int(fs * chunk_duration)  # Each read length in number of samples.
    return pyaudio.PyAudio().open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                  channels=1,
                                  rate=fs,
                                  input=True,
                                  frames_per_buffer=chunk_samples,
                                  stream_callback=callback)



def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global run, data, silence_threshold
    data0 = np.frombuffer(in_data, dtype='int16')
    if np.abs(data0).mean() < silence_threshold:
        sys.stdout.write('-')
        return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue
    else:
        sys.stdout.write('.')
        data = np.append(data, data0)
    if len(data) > feed_samples:
        data = data[-feed_samples:]
        q.put(data)  # Process data async by sending a queue.
    return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue




def trigger_action():
    # When the trigger word is said, do an action
    sys.stdout.write('1')
    '''chime = AudioSegment.from_wav("audio_examples/chime.wav")
    play(chime)
'''


# Each model input data duration in seconds, need to be an integer numbers of chunk_duration
feed_samples = int(fs * feed_duration)
assert feed_duration / chunk_duration == int(feed_duration / chunk_duration)
q = Queue()  # Queue to communiate between the audio callback and main thread
data = np.zeros(feed_samples, dtype='int16')  # Data buffer for the input wavform


run = True
stream = get_audio_input_stream(callback, chunk_duration=chunk_duration, fs=fs)
stream.start_stream()
count = 0

print("START...")
try:
    while run and count < 4:
        data = q.get()
        preds = detect_triggerword_spectrum(get_spectrogram(data))
#         print(preds)
        new_trigger = has_new_triggerword(preds, chunk_duration, feed_duration)
        if new_trigger:
            count = count + 1
            trigger_action()
except(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    # for KeyboardInterrupt use Ctrl+F2 in Pycharm or Ctrl+C in normal Python
    run = False
finally:
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
```

In my output although there is no error, but still the program is at a stand still.

Output :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python3 rasberry_script.py 
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround40.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround40
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround41
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround50
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround51
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.surround71.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround71
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:823:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=6,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958:{AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2  CARD 0}
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
START...
```

My microphone is on USB port and my speaker is on the Jack.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: b1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1], device 0: bcm2835 HDMI 1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 4/4
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
card 1: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 4/4
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
card 2: Device [USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```